# How to update pull-requesting site after pull request has been merged?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Let's say that GitHub repo `B` sends a pull request to GitHub repo `A`, and suppose that the pull won't go through without resolving some conflicts and merging.

Therefore, in order to accept the changes proposed by `B`, the owner of `A` makes the pull request from an offline repo, performs the merge, and pushes the merge to `A`.  Now `A` is at least one commit ahead of `B`.

How does `B` now update itself to be in sync with `A`?  Can this be done entirely from within the GitHub web interface?

(I imagine that one answer to the first question would be that the owner of `B` could pull the contents of the `A` repo, and then push the resulting state to the `B` repo, but I was wondering if there's a way to update the `B` repo directly from the GitHub web interface.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to achieve this using GitHub's web interface is creating a reverse pull request. This however comes at the cost of an additional merge commit which is usually not desirable as it sums up and new pull requests from `B` to `A` will include all those unneccesary commits.

It probably is possible to use the [„Git Data“ API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/) to merge some branches, but it is easier and safer to do it on the command line.

---

The strategy I recommend to others is this one:

1. Never ever modify your `master` or whatever the mainline branch is called
2. Base your pull request branches on your `master`
3. Whenever there are changes to the upstream `master` integrate them by fast forwarding your `master` to the upstream one.

That way your pull requests will stay nice and clean and you won't have issues with rejected commits popping up in subsequent pull requests.