# How to update a fork on Github to upstream version without pumping everything though my local computer?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Supposing I:

1. Forked a 100 MB repository;
2. Added just one little commit to it;
3. After month, the upstream repositlry got a lot of commits and now 200 MB;
4. Now I want to update my forked repository.

I see two ways of doing it:

1. Just push the updated version like usual. Drawback: it uploads 100 MB to network. Inefficient.
2. Delete the forked repository entirely and re-fork it, then upload the changes. Drawback: hassle to set up things.

How to do it efficiently?

Comment: I don't see any other way than the ones you've listed.

Comment: So shall I file a wishlist issue to Github?

Comment: I've already contacted them here https://github.com/contact I've always needed this feature to update small PRs, but I've also pointed them to your use case. I guess you could contact them as well to better explain your point.

Comment: Here is GitHub's answer: "Thanks for the suggestion! I've added a +1 to this item on our Feature Request List. No promises if/when this might be added, but we really appreciate the thoughtful feedback."

Answer (score 0):

Despite I'm yet to see a repository that grows *that* fast<sup>1</sup> I'll try to answer:

1. **Method two** will have a much larger impact on network as you'll have to re`clone` the entire repository.
2. There was [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21591645/782822) a few days before: It is possible to do a merge via GitHubs Web interface by creating a **reverse pull request**, but this will create additional merge commits and you still have to *download* those 100 MB.
3. In case you have access to **a server** via a greater bandwidth: Perform the update on that machine, it will go faster, but you still have to *download* those 100 MB.

In short: Simply go for your first point, it is the most straight forward one.

<sup>1</sup> My last clone of the entire history of the linux kernel is sized 900 MB.

Comment: `Method two will have a much larger impact on network as you'll have to reclone ...` -> No, because of both upstream and a fork are different remotes of the same local repository. If I already cloned upstream then I don't need to download entire fork. I also use `--reference` in addition to that.

Comment: `still have to download those 100 MB` -> No, for the same reason. For example, I track many versions of linux kernel (official, pf, zenstable), but I don't download duplicate info each time.